# How to pass an activity intent to another class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an arraylist. I get this arraylist from another activity with using `Bundle` like that :

```
Bundle name = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> namevalue = name.getStringArrayList("name");
```

I want to use same arraylist in a different class. But i can't get with using `getIntent()` method becoz of my class is not an activity. Is there a way to pass this arraylist?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something.  Could you explain why passing this arraylist to a different class is different than sharing any other data with another different class? That is, why couldn't you simply pass it as a method parameter (push) or provide a getter method for the other class to use (pull) like you would a regular Java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass it to the class as a parameter (via constructor or through another method):

```
Bundle name = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> namevalue = name.getStringArrayList("name"); 

YourClass yc = new YourClass(namevalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a setter in your class:

```
public class MyClass {

  List<String> names;

  public void setNames(List<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
  }
}
```

Then call setNames from your Activity.